# Error while login phase in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis

I have configured a web application to IIS host and is working fine but when I am trying to have my login aspx page and SQL connection and trying to login and I get this error:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.

Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="where is the database";Integrated Security=True

Source Error:
Line 20:         protected void Login1_Authenticate1(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
Line 21:         {
Line 22:             if (Membership.ValidateUser(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password) == true)
Line 23:             {
Line 24:                 Login1.Visible = true;

Here is the Stack Trace:

[image]
)

Comment: Perhaps you should share your connection string.

Comment: Have you `See the Windows Application event log for error details.`?

Comment: Yes but I did not find any errors! @rptHarry

Comment: I have added the connection string @DionV.